# App is launched but not able to perform further actions (App automation using appium)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I am new in mobile app automation

I have successfully launched Google Playstore application in my android device. but,i can not click on next tab "GAMES".

## My Code

```
package com.automate.app.screens;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class FirstTest {
    
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
    
    @Test
    public void FirstCheck() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {
        
        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "ZY223NZKZQ"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
        try {
            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.vending:id/title")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

## Error

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Feb 12, 2019 4:26:10 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
FAILED: FirstCheck
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.lambda$0(HasSessionDetails.java:49)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectSpliterators$1.lambda$forEachRemaining$1(CollectSpliterators.java:117)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at com.google.common.collect.CollectSpliterators$1.forEachRemaining(CollectSpliterators.java:117)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetails(HasSessionDetails.java:52)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getSessionDetail(HasSessionDetails.java:56)
    at io.appium.java_client.HasSessionDetails.getPlatformName(HasSessionDetails.java:65)
    at io.appium.java_client.internal.JsonToMobileElementConverter.<init>(JsonToMobileElementConverter.java:49)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at com.automate.app.screens.FirstTest.FirstCheck(FirstTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

## I have added

Appium jar
java-client-7.0.0.jar

Selenium dependency

org.seleniumhq.selenium
selenium-java
3.14.0

appium version-1.10.0

I have googled about error but not found proper solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Anonygoose It worked for me. Downloaded Apache Commons Lang 3.10 and all errors vanished and further actions are performed smoothly. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing Apache Commons Lang.  If you're using Maven, add it as a dependency, otherwise download it from the link below and put the jar on your classpath.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi